# Is there anyway assign custom keyboard shorcut for noise music player?

Tags: release-freya, music, audio

I want to assign some custom keyboard shortcut for noise music player.
When it running background , using keyboard want to paly/pause or change music.

Is there anyway assign those custom keyboard shortcut for noise music player?

Amarok have option assign keyboard shortcut but when it's running on background ,shortcut not work :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the 'Keyboard' plug in System Settings it's possible to do this.

`System Settings` --> `Keyboard` --> `Shortcuts` --> Media gives options to change the shortcuts for playing/pausing and other media functions.

Just click the shortcut you want to change and press the desired key-combination.

[image]

Comment: @Ravan, assigned combination for Pause for instance doesn't  work, but for Volume UP/Down and Previous/Next track it works though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but sadly "Shift + <" combination doesn't work, "Shift + >" does though. Actually "Ctrl + ," and "Ctrl + ." will fit perfectly for chosing previous and next track.